# Return value of add_menu_page

Tags: add-menu-page

I've read this on codex and seem some themes use it but never understood how it worked.

> `(string) $hookname` used internally to track menu page callbacks for outputting the page inside the `global $menu` array

I can't seem to understand the codex's explanation. Can some one enlighten me on how can we use the return value and what are the uses of it?

Answer (score 1):

One important use is enqueue script / style only on specific plugin/admin pages.

```
<?php
    add_action('init', 'my_plugin_admin_page');

    function my_plugin_admin_page()
    {
        //create the menu page
        $hook = add_menu_page(....);

        //use the hook for this page for enqueuing
        add_action('admin_print_styles-' . $hook, 'my_plugin_admin_styles');
    }

    function my_plugin_admin_styles()
    {
        //enqueue the style/script here
    }
?>
```

This is one use I know.

Comment: You should only add admin pages on `admin_init`.

Answer (score 1):

*Hope code is self-explanatory.*

```
// Add a new submenu page and also add a load handler for it to process POSTs
($hook_name = add_submenu_page(
    'plugins.php', // Under plugins menu
    'Title',
    'Menu',
    'activate_plugins', // Administrators
    'slug',
    function(){ // Visual is here ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <h2>Sub-Page Title</h2>
            <!-- Subpage visual output comes here -->
        </div>
<?php })) and (add_action("load-{$hook_name}", function(){ // Hook the load here
    if(!strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST')){
        $_POST =  stripslashes_deep($_POST); // Fix this WP BS security joke
        // Handle a POST request
        // ... Do stuff with $_POST
    }elseif(!strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'GET')){
        // Handle a GET (normal) request
        // ... Usually not needed
    }
}));
```

**Have fun!**

Comment: Note, that anonymous/closure functions are not available for PHP v5.2 and before. As WP requirements is PHP 5.2(.1?), this may not work everywhere. You could do a `version_compare()` before the statement and in case switch to lambda functions. Anyway, there are much easier ways to do this (including readability & debugging/backtracing). +1 for the effort anyway :)

Comment: I know but I can no longer poison the function-space since moving completely to PHP 5.3 :) And it's a lot easier for me to post examples. Those that don't know them... learn something new and might be tempted to update PHP. Those that do can quickly understand and convert the code for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I see this with mixed feelings: Shared hosting (which is majority) mostly have no chance to decide about the exact version number of PHP they are running. Also: Try to remove an action later on, when the name starts with "\0lambda_XYZ" or some funky closer alphanumeric chaos :) Normally this means catching all functions attached to a hook, do some slow `preg_match` or similar and attach what you need again. Lots of effort which is IMHO often not worth it.

Comment: @kaiser [Hostgator](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/php-5-3) _(no affiliate link, shared hosting support for PHP 5.3)_

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't mean that you can do it _everywhere_. I just meant that it's necessary to state the fact that this is 5.3+ only as lots of non tech savy people will run into problems. Also the other problems remain.

Comment: I don't wanna continue the debate but I want to explain something: If you need to remove an action later on, avoid Closures. But where you don't, use them as there's no point adding single-use functions to the global function-space. It's all about informed programming decisions. (Closures are Objects so preg_match will fail, you need === to compare exact object instances. Closures are created at compile time (fast), lambda-s at runtime (very slow). Closure object are named \Closure.) --- And I apologize for my (unintentional) utter disregard to beginners.

Comment: [Sure about the Q regarding speed?](http://php.net/manual/de/functions.anonymous.php#102785). Anyway, nothing to apologize and I didn't mean to push that hard on that topic. :)

Comment: Ok. • Lambda function = create_function(). • Closure (invokable object, object that implements __invoke (at the core)) = Closure (anonymous function). • Function = regular named PHP function. ••• That guy just proved Closures are faster than (named) declared functions. Seriously! No lambda there, just a misnamed Closure variable.